# Using enum in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to define LogLevel variable l?

Currently I have error:

```
 Error  3   error C2228: left of '.LogLevelDebug' must have class/struct/union
```

Code:

```
typedef enum LogLevel
{
    LogLevelDebug = 0,
    LogLevelError = 1,
    LogLevelInfo = 2,
    LogLevelTrace = 3,
} LogLevel;



int main ()
{
logLevel l = LogLevel.LogLevelDebug;
}
```

Comment: I think "logLevel l" needs to be "LogLevel l"?  Also, this question seems to be more about enumerations than unions.

Comment: It's an enum, not a union. Just LogLevelDebug.

Comment: Remove the `typedef`.  It's not needed in C++, confuses people and makes things difficult, as you have found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [c++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) it would be:

```
enum class LogLevel
{
 LogLevelDebug = 0,
 LogLevelError = 1,
 LogLevelInfo = 2,
 LogLevelTrace = 3,
};



int main ()
{
 LogLevel l = LogLevel::LogLevelDebug;
}
```

in a previous C++ standard:

```
enum LogLevel
{
    LogLevelDebug = 0,
    LogLevelError = 1,
    LogLevelInfo = 2,
    LogLevelTrace = 3,
};

int main ()
{
    LogLevel l = LogLevelDebug;
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness I've been in C# so long I'd forgotten about ::

Comment: Last I read, even in C++03 `enum`s can be read as a legal scope on their names (ie, `LogLevel::LogLevelDebug` may be legal in C++03).  Something about the `enum` being part of a more general class of thing...  I guess it matters more if your compiler and potential future compilers support it.